# Where should I create Index in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I'm studying about how to improve Mongoose query time while building my Nodejs API. Then I found out Mongoose Index. My question is where should I create the Index for a schema? Like creating the index in every http requests or just creating it when the server starts?

Thank you guys a lot!

Comment: Aren't index created at the database level and you query on your index to get  a faster result?

Comment: adding index at the moment when creating a schema??? But at that moment, maybe I dont know which fields to add index to, I mean there are some queries that happen when you programming that you dont think about them at the beginning...

Comment: you can add indexes later too, and you need know which fields to index, if your requirements change that quickly.... then you're in for a lot of code re-writing

Answer (score 0):

You should create the index after entering into the mongodb terminal
command is:

```
db.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.createIndex({COLUMN_NAME: -1})
```

After this, your index is created.